# CKM_CAST5_CBC_PAD on LunaSA

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm

I have a LunaSA HSM and i'm trying to unwrap a PKCS#8 formatted private key with a CAST5 secret key? The mechanism to use is [`CKM_CAST5_CBC_PAD`](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.840.113533.7.66.10.html) the OID of which is `1.2.840.113533.7.66.10`.

Unfortunately when i run the `C_UnwrapKey` function using the above mechanism with the specified secret key, the HSM returns with `CKM_MECHANISM_INVALID` which according to PKCS11 means that the mechanism is not supported for the specified cryptographic operation.

How can I unwrap my PKCS#8 private key using `CKM_CAST5_CBC_PAD`?

Answer (score 1):

With `CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID` your PKCS#11 library is telling you that "An invalid mechanism was specified to the cryptographic operation".

Are you sure that your PKCS#11 library supports `CKM_CAST5_CBC_PAD` mechanism? You can check by simply calling `C_GetMechanismList()` and checking whether this mechanism is present in the returned list.

Comment: I have verified the mechanism exists in the C_GetMechanismList however, cryptoki still returns CKM_MECHANISM_INVALID.

Comment: Have you also called C_GetMechanismInfo() for CKM_CAST5_CBC_PAD mechanism to check whether your PKCS#11 library supports key unwrapping with this mechanism? You should check CKF_UNWRAP flag in returned CK_MECHANISM_INFO structure.

Comment: Yes i did and CKF_UNWRAP is set.

Comment: Well then CKM_MECHANISM_INVALID error is really weird but I have seen some PKCS#11 implementations returning CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID also for an incorrect mechanism parameters. Are you passing IV as a parameter? Can you enable any kind of PKCS#11 library internal logging (should be documented by vendor)?